# dynamic textbox jquery focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors

i am creating a dynamic text box of input type with the help of following
code
i am not able to set the focus on the input type.

```
var elem = document.createElement("input");
elem.type = "text";
elem.id = "txtParent";
elem.setAttribute('onblur', 'SetSpanValueForParent("' + spnText.id + '")');
$(elem).focus();
$(spnText).append(elem);
```

i have also tried doing this
elem.focus();

can u provide that one line statement how can i achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to append the input, before setting the focus().

Elements  can have focus only if they are visible.

Example:

```
function fx(spnText)
{
  var elem = document.createElement("input");
  elem.type = "text";
  elem.id = "txtParent";
  elem.setAttribute('onblur', 'SetSpanValueForParent("' + spnText.id + '")');
  $(spnText).append(elem);
  //a little delay before setting the focus
  setTimeout(function(){elem.focus()},50);
}
```

Comment: Use setTimeout to have a little delay between appending and setting the focus(). Added an example above.

Comment: thank you Dr molle it worked perfectly but how does the time out

Comment: made the focus on the particular thing.