# Adding info to dynamic text boxes jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been making an app that adds tables based off the number you type in one text box. I've been able to make a button that generates tables based off the number and then a box shows the number of tables after each addition.

What I've been trying to do is have the ability to type in a name or any text and have that be displayed in the 'Name' box when clicking the 'Add now' button. 
I've been trying to tweak the existing add function to show text typed into the second box, but can't figure it out.

live version here: 
http://codepen.io/BabinecJ/pen/BRjJbw

```js
$('[name="cand_no" ]').on('change', function() {
  // Not checking for Invalid input
  if (this.value != '') {
    var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    ///Click add button add count number + table

    $(function() {
      $('#add').bind('click', function() {
        $('#mytbody');
        var count = $('#mytbody').children('tr').length;
        $('#counter').html(count);
        
        var name = $("#tname").val();
        $(name).after($("#tname"));
        $('#tname').html(name);
        ///need to find enter coder name 

        var name = $("#tname").val();
        $('#name').html(name);
      });
    });

    /// Figuring out way to disable enter key being pressed

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('cand_no').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      });
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
      // Clone the Template
      var $cloned = $('.template tbody').clone();
      // For each number added append the template row
      $('#studentTable tbody').append($cloned.html());
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.template {
  border-style: solid;
}

#cand_no {
  background-color: red;
}

#add {
  color: red;
  margin-right: 770px;
  margin-top: -35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label><strong>Number of Rows</strong></label>
  <label><input name="cand_no"  type="text" placeholder="Type Number of Rows" id="cand_no" /></label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</p>
<button id="add" style="float:right;">Add row</button>

<p>
  <label><strong>Your Name</strong></label>
  <label><input name="tname" id="cand_no" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Name"  /></label>
  <span class="clear"></span>
</p>
<div class="cand_fields">
  <table id="studentTable" width="630" border="solid">
    <tbody id="mytbody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Number of rows:
            <span id="counter">
              </span>
            </p>
        </td>

        <td>Name
          <p id="tname">
            </span>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="tname" type="text" placeholder="name" required="required" id="tname" /></td>

        <td><input name="cand_pos" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="template" id=".template" style="display:none ">
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td><input name="cand_name" type="text" placeholder="Count" required="required" id="count" /></td>

      <td><input name="cand_pos" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic textbox jquery focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312516/dynamic-textbox-jquery-focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the MDN documentation for *id*: "*The **id** [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>

So update the *id* attribute of the destination element (i.e. `<p id="tname">`) to be unique. This block:

```
<td> <p>Number of rows: <p id="counter"></span></p></td>

<td>Name<p id="tname"></span></p></td>
```

becomes something like this:

```
<td> <p>Number of rows: <p id="counter"></span></p></td>

<td>Name<p id="aname"></span></p></td>
```

And then update the JavaScript code that updates that element like this:

```
 $('#aname').html(name);
```

See a demonstration of this below:

```js
$('[name="cand_no" ]').on('change', function() {
  // Not checking for Invalid input
  if (this.value != '') {
    var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    ///Click add button add count number + table

    $(function() {
      $('#add').bind('click', function() {
        $('#mytbody');
        var count = $('#mytbody').children('tr').length;
        $('#counter').html(count);
        ///need to find enter coder name 
        var name = $("#tname").val();
        $('#aname').html(name);
      });
    });
    /// Figuring out way to disable enter key being pressed
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('cand_no').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
      // Clone the Template
      var $cloned = $('.template tbody').clone();
      // For each number added append the template row
      $('#studentTable tbody').append($cloned.html());
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.template {
  border-style: solid;
}

#cand_no {
  background-color: red;
}

#add {
  color: red;
  margin-right: 770px;
  margin-top: -35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label><strong>Number of Rows</strong></label>
  <label><input name="cand_no"  type="text" placeholder="Type Number of Rows" id="cand_no" /></label>

<div style="float: right; width: 40px">
    <button id="add">Add row</button>
</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</p>
<p>
  <label><strong>Your Name</strong></label>
  <label><input name="tname" id="tname" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Name"  /></label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</p>


<div class="cand_fields">
  <table id="studentTable" width="630" border="solid">
    <tbody id="mytbody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Number of rows:
            <p id="counter">
              </span>
            </p>
        </td>

        <td id="tname" width="0">Nameee
          <p id="aname">
            </span>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="tname" type="text" placeholder="name" required="required" id="tname" /></td>

        <td><input name="cand_pos" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="template" id=".template" style="display:none ">
  <table>





    <tr>
      <td><input name="cand_name" type="text" placeholder="Count" required="required" id="count" /></td>

      <td><input name="cand_pos" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sub>